# pandas cut(): how to convert nans? Or to convert the output to non-categorical?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I am using pandas.cut() on dataframe columns with nans. I need to run groupby on the output of pandas.cut(), so I need to convert nans to something else (in the output, not in the input data), otherwise groupby will stupidly and infuriatingly ignore them.

I understand that cut() now outputs categorical data, but I cannot find a way to add a category to the output. I have tried add_categories(), which runs with no warning nor errors, but doesn't work because the categories are not added and, indeed, fillna fails for this very reason. A minimalist example is below.

Any ideas?

Or is there maybe an easy way to convert this categorical object to a non-categorical one? I have tried np.asarray() but with no luck - it becomes an array containing an Interval object

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x=[np.nan,4,6]
intervals =[-np.inf,4,np.inf]
out_nolabels=pd.cut(x,intervals)
out_labels=pd.cut(x,intervals, labels=['<=4','>4'])
out_nolabels.add_categories(['missing'])
out_labels.add_categories(['missing'])

print(out_labels)
print(out_nolabels)

out_labels=out_labels.fillna('missing')
out_nolabels=out_nolabels.fillna('missing')
```

Comment: Could you add an expected output if possible.

Comment: out_labels should become: ['missing','<=4', '>4'] so that, when I do a groupby, I don't lose the count of the nans. If I do a groupby now, with the output as it is, I do lose the nans, which is infuriating.

Comment: Are you trying to groupby all nans as one group? Do add a snippet of your actual. Two Nan's as a float are not equal in other words are different. So pandas developers are clever to ignore that.

Comment: Yes, all the nans must become a category in the groupby. Groupby should show as categories: <=4, >4 and missing.

Answer (score 11):

As the documentation say out of the bounds data will be consider as Na categorical object, so you cant use fillna's with some constant in categorical data `since the new value you are filling is not in that categories`

> Any NA values will be NA in the result. Out of bounds values will be
>   NA in the resulting Categorical object

You cant use `x.fillna('missing')` because `missing` is not in the category of `x` but you can do `x.fillna('>4')` because `>4` is in the category.

We can use np.where here to overcome that

```
x = pd.cut(df['id'],intervals, labels=['<=4','>4'])

np.where(x.isnull(),'missing',x)
array(['<=4', '<=4', '<=4', '<=4', 'missing', 'missing'], dtype=object)
```

Or `add_categories` to the values i.e

```
x = pd.cut(df['id'],intervals, labels=['<=4','>4']).values.add_categories('missing')
x.fillna('missing')

[<=4, <=4, <=4, <=4, missing, missing]
Categories (3, object): [<=4 < >4 < missing]
```

If you want to group nan's and keep the dtype one way of doing it is by casting it to str i.e If you have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,4,np.nan,np.nan],'value':[4,5,6,7,8,1]})

df.groupby(df.id.astype(str)).mean()
```

Output :

```
     id  value
id             
1.0  1.0    5.0
4.0  4.0    7.0
nan  NaN    4.5
```

Comment: So my mistake was running pd.cut(.....).add_categories() instead of pd.cut(...),values.add_categories() . I still don't understand why the code ran with no error or warnings, though. But thanks!

Comment: Yes. When you used pd.cut they return data with a series dtype layer. To get rid of that u need  `.values`