# Pandas cut function with None in data set

Tags: python, pandas

In my data set, there's a column that looks like, for example:

`[111, 112, None, 113, 114, 115, 116, None, 117, 118, 119]`

I want to bin this column into, let's say 3 bins, so that I'd get

`[0, 0, None, 0, 1, 1, 1, None, 2, 2, 2]`

How do I do this with pandas.cut? It would not accept None as an element in the input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas cut(): how to convert nans? Or to convert the output to non-categorical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053770/pandas-cut-how-to-convert-nans-or-to-convert-the-output-to-non-categorical)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC,

```
s = pd.Series([111, 112, None, 113, 114, 115, 116, None, 117, 118, 119])

pd.cut(s, bins=[0, 113, 116, 120], labels=[0, 1, 2])
```

Output:

```
0       0
1       0
2     NaN
3       0
4       1
5       1
6       1
7     NaN
8       2
9       2
10      2
dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 < 2]
```

Or try `qcut`,

```
pd.qcut(s, 3, labels=[0, 1, 2])
```

Output:

```
0       0
1       0
2     NaN
3       0
4       1
5       1
6       1
7     NaN
8       2
9       2
10      2
dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 < 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The reason why it didn't work for me is because my input was a numpy array. Also I read another thread recommended, and it would work if I replace all the `None` with `np.nan`